# Create own app that communicate with Whatsapp

Tags: java, android

I want to make my own plug-in/app that can interface with WhatsApp.
In particular my idea is to make a plug-in(app) that add survey function on the WhatsApp app.

I know that I can't modify the source of WhatsApp, In fact I will make my own app(of course user must download it for reach the survey),  with a command or button  i run the form with varius options and when user tap send button my app send message (in broadcast) to all the users and then I manage the situation.

Is possible to do it?

I know WhatsApp don't make API for developers (Is true or not? I don't find on google the APIs)

Comment: You can share with whatsApp using the Intent.
You can create an app which will start the WhatsApp to share your message. Whatsapp do not provide the API as far as I know .

Comment: @SanjeetAjnabee The my first idea is to add the possibility to do survey(for survey i mean 'Events' like facebook, you know it?) in the whatsapp but i can't do this because Whatsapp do not provide the API.So i try make my own app...that try to interface with wp
Can you link me documentation of the Intent?

Comment: @S1ngh Like you have been told above, Whatsapp is not open source. What you are asking for, "try to interface" is exaclty what an API does. And because Whatsapp is not open sourced, there's no documentation. All you can get to work with is [this sharing intent for a single contact in java](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012) and  [this repository for python users](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup)